# How to get font Avant Garde condensed?

Tags: fonts, xetex

For the title of my thesis, I would like to use the Avant Garde (pag) font in a condensed shape, and bold font weight. I remember to have done this some years ago, but the document from that time doesn't compile anymore on my system, probably because of missing files or packages.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

% None of these seems to have any effect...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fontencoding{T1}

\begin{document}
    This should be the default serif font.

    {\sffamily This should be the default sans-serif font.}

    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont This should be Avant Garde.}

    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pag}\fontseries{b}\selectfont This should be Avant Garde bold.}

    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pag}\fontseries{c}\selectfont This should be Avant Garde condensed.}

    {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pag}\fontseries{bc}\selectfont This should be Avant Garde condensed and bold.}
\end{document}
```

The normal Avant Garde and its bold shape are displayed correctly. But for the last two, I get these warnings:

> Font shape 'T1/pag/c/n' undefined(Font) using 'T1/pag/m/n' instead

> Font shape 'T1/pag/bc/n' undefined(Font) using 'T1/pag/m/n' instead

...and they are just displayed as Avant Garde normal.

For the thesis, I'm not using the article class, but scrbook, but as the same problem exists for article, I reduced the MWE to that.
I'm compiling with xelatex, but latex, pdflatex and lualatex fail as well.

OS: Manjaro Linux (Arch-based)

Do I need to install the condensed series of Avant Garde, and if yes, how and where?

Comment: You are tagging the question `xetex` and yet using `fontenc`, which works for `pdftex`. Which is it?

Comment: Ah, didn't know that the two didn't work together. At some point, I just threw more packages in, hoping that one would fix this. You can omit `fontenc`, still the same issue. As I wrote, I'm using `xelatex` to compile.

Comment: there is imho no condensed variant in texlive or on ctan. If you want to use it you will have to find a suitable font elsewhere. Once you have it you can load it with fontspec.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, okay. I guess it must have been preinstalled on the OS I was using back then. I downloaded a TTF version of the font, installed it, and loaded it with `\newfontfamily\pagc{AvantGarde LT CondMedium}`. Thank you!